# Making directories in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, upload

I have this jQuery upload plugin that allows a user to upload multiple files at a time. I went ahead and tweaked the upload directory and told php to create a new folder by the date and time of each upload.

what's weird to me is that after the upload, the new folder gets created in the folder above "files" and not INSIDE the "files" folder. But when the image url is returned it gives me the correct path of where the file should be but it's not actually there. Does that make sense?

```
$date = date('mdy');
$this - > options = array(
    'script_url' = > $this - > get_full_url().'/',
    'upload_dir' = > dirname($this - > get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/'.mkdir($date).'_'.time().'/',
    'upload_url' = > $this - > get_full_url().'/files/'.$date.'_'.time().'/',
```

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the just created directory?

Comment: @davey yes, that has nothing to do with the problem though. The script is creating the directory but not where I'm telling it to make the directory. And what i just noticed is that php seems to be making two folders. It makes a folder by the date in the WRONG place, but strangely makes a folder of just the system time of which it was uploaded in the CORRECT place.. but yeah things are quite weird.

Answer (score 0):

Something not directly related to your question: You call the function time() twice and expect it to return the same thing - this will work in many cases, but it is far from sure.

Please change your code a bit like this:

```
$path = date('mdy')."_".time();
* * * .mkdir($path);
* * * '/files/'.$path;
```

This way you can be sure you always work with the same path.